# How to split a string of characters in a 2D dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, split

So i have to put and split this information that is stored in the string Content:

```
ID_PLAYER_1==>Joueur 1---Player 1
ID_AMMO==>Muni---Ammo
```

in a 2-d dictionnary that looks like this:

```
Dictionary<Language, Dictionary<string, string>> items = 
    new Dictionary<Language, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

the enumeration Language will determinate the position of one the characters based on the language of the word.

So in the end it would look like this:

```
Player 1  Ammo
Joueur 1  Muni
```

I have never used a 2-d dictionary before and i am confused on how i am supposed to split it like that. the method i am working on to do the tranformation of the text like is like this:

```
public ErrorCode Parse()
{    
    string Content = "@ID_PLAYER_1==>Joueur 1---Player 1
    ID_AMMO==>Muni---Ammo"
    //Content has the value: " ID_PLAYER_1==>Joueur 1---Player 1
    //ID_AMMO==>Muni---Ammo"
    items[0].Add (Content.Split(//splitting method), Content.Split())
    return ErrorCode.MISSING_FIELD;
}
```

Enumeration Language:

```
public enum Language
{
  French,
  English
}
```

ErrorCode:

```
public enum ErrorCode
{
 OK,
 BAD_FILE_FORMAT,
 MISSING_FIELD,
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: is this edit better?

Comment: I don't understand what is the expected value, what should go on `Language` and what should go in the inner Dictionary?

Comment: Language is the first key and it will just indicate if the content contains words in french or English. On the inner dictionary, it contains the id of the word and the word itself. here is an better example: items[Language.English].Add("ID_AMMO","Ammo");

Comment: made a more clear edit

Comment: it's still not clear to me what you are asking. Are you having trouble with splitting the content string, or are you having trouble with writing to the 2D-dictionary? Or both?

Comment: splitting the content string to place it correctly on the dictionary.

Comment: @juasjuasi the answer provided by BrunoLM is as good as it's going to get. It explains both the use of the 2D-dictionairy as the splitting of the contentstring pretty well. If you don't have any more questions, don't forget to markt he answer as correct..

Comment: yeah, just did that, i just need to implement it into my case since i have two inputs to split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes strings as the separator.

So first you can split the ID from the content. And then split the content in French / English.

With all the values put them where you want, ex:

```
var items = new Dictionary<Language, Dictionary<string, string>>();
items.Add(Language.English, new Dictionary<string, string>() );
items.Add(Language.French, new Dictionary<string, string>() );

var input = "ID_PLAYER_1==>Joueur 1---Player 1";

// parts[0] = ID ; parts[1] = Content
var parts = input.Split(new string[] { "==>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// values[0] = french ; values[1] = english
var values = parts[1].Split(new string[] { "---" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var key = parts[0]; // ID
var french = values[0];
var english = values[1];

// put them in the Dictionary
items[Language.English].Add(key, english);
items[Language.French].Add(key, french);
```

Comment: You have to first create an empty dictionary of dictionaries.  Then add an empty english dictionary and an empty french dictionary to it.  Then you would just do `dictionaries[Language.English].Add(key, english)` and `dictionaries[Language.French].Add(key, french)`  In other words, you *don't* want a new dictionary for each key.